# Equations Alignment

Tags: equations

I am having an issue with my equations. I would like to align 3 equations within 3 columns.

Currently my text is as follows:

```
\begin{align*}
 & = x^2 -12x +67 & = 6x^2 +24x +18 & = 9x^2 +7x +18 \\
 & = (x^2-12x+36)-36-67 & x^2+4x+3 & = 9\left(x^2+\dfrac{9}{7}x+2\right) \\ 
 & = (x-6)^2+31 & = (x+2)^2-1 &=  9\left(x^2+2\cdot \dfrac{45}{70} + \dfrac{45}{70}^2 -\dfrac{45}{70}^2 +2\right) \\
 & & & = 9\left[\left(x+\dfrac{45}{70}\right)^2+\dfrac{311}{196}\right]
\end{align*}
```

and the result:

[image]

Please help me find out out to space and align correctly my equations.

Thank you so much

Comment: It is not clear what you want. What would you like to be different?

Comment: Thank you for asking, I would like the equations to be equally spaced. As you can see, there are different equations. 

x^2 - 12x + 67
6x^2+24x+18
9x^2+7x+18

I would like them to be equally spaced in terms of the horizontal and also aligned with each other

Comment: The first equation x^2-12x+67 is correctly placed and aligned with the rest of it. However, the 2 others are all together which I don't want.

Comment: I would like it to be as 3 blocks of equations equally spaced in between them.

Comment: Mathematically there would need to be a factor 6 in the second and third equation in the middle column :)

Answer (score 4):

The `align` environment requires *two* `&` per column from the second one: one to introduce the new column, one to set the alignment point within this column.

Maybe you might want to use the `flalign` environment in the present case. You can compare both solutions in the following code.

I also took the liberty to correct the calculations in the 3rd column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    & = x² -12x +67 & & = 6x² +24x +18 & & = 9x² +7x +18 \\
    & = (x²-12x+36)-36-67 & & = 6(x²+4x+3) & & = 9\left(x²+\dfrac{7}{9}x+2\right) \\
    & = (x-6)²+31 & & = 6[(x+2)²-1] & & = 9\Biggl[x²+2 · \frac{7}{18} +{ \biggl(\frac{7}{18}\biggr)}^{\!2} - \biggl(\frac{7}{18}\biggr)^{\!2} +2\Biggr] \\
    & & & & & = 9\Biggl[\biggl(x+\frac{7}{18}\biggr)²+\frac{599}{324}\Biggr]
\end{align*}

\begin{flalign*}
  & = x² -12x +67 & & = 6x² +24x +18 & & = 9x² +7x +18 \\
  & = (x²-12x+36)-36-67 & & = 6(x²+4x+3) & & = 9\left(x²+\dfrac{7}{9}x+2\right) \\
  & = (x-6)²+31 & & = 6[(x+2)²-1] & & = 9\Biggl[x²+2 · \frac{7}{18} +{ \biggl(\frac{7}{18}\biggr)}^{\!2} - \biggl(\frac{7}{18}\biggr)^{\!2} +2\Biggr] \\
  & & & & & = 9\Biggl[\biggl(x+\frac{7}{18}\biggr)²+\frac{599}{324}\Biggr]
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to thank you very much for your help ! Thank you for correcting my math, appreciated it ^ ^ !

Comment: You're welcome. I'm always glad when I can help!

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 & = x^2 -12x +67       && = 6x^2 +24x +18   && = 9x^2 +7x +18 \\
 & = (x^2-12x+36)-36-67 && = x^2+4x+3        && = 9\left(x^2+\dfrac{9}{7}x+2\right) \\
 & = (x-6)^2+31         && = (x+2)^2-1       && =  9\left(x^2+2\cdot \dfrac{45}{70} 
                                            + \dfrac{45}{70}^2 -\dfrac{45}{70}^2 +2\right) \\
 &                      &&                   && = 9\left[\left(x+\dfrac{45}{70}\right)^2
                                                +\dfrac{311}{196}\right]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The {3} should be removed.

Comment: thank you, i forget to remove it when test `alignat` ...